# leftCalloutAccessoryView image reference?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Hello i'm building a mapbased App when i'm tapping on the Accessory i perform a segue to a profile page which gives information about the pin location. Now i have a image in my LeftCalloutAccesoryView which a i want to show on the detail page. Now i'm curious if there is a method to get the image which a set on LeftCalloutAccesoryView. I add the images dynamically.

my accessorycontroltapped code:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    companytitle = view.annotation.title;
    description = view.annotation.subtitle;
    thumbprofileimage = view.image;
    //thumbprofileimage = [(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:pin.image];
    //UIImageView *leftIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    //leftIconView = [view.leftCalloutAccessoryView [[UIImageView alloc]];
    //view.leftCalloutAccessoryView;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPlattegrondDetails" sender:self];
}
```

my set pins code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mpView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[RouteAnnotation class]]) {

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView =
        (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                              initWithAnnotation:annotation
                              reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        leftIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
        [leftIconView setImage:pin.image];
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView;
        //annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Does someone have the solution of getting a reference to the image so i can send this image to the detail page?

Comment: In viewForAnnotation, the image is set using `pin.image`.  What is the `pin` object and how is it set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already part way there with your `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method.

Create a property to keep a reference to the image from the tapped callout:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *selectedCalloutImage;
```

And update the delegate method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    companytitle = view.annotation.title;
    description = view.annotation.subtitle;
    thumbprofileimage = view.image;
    //thumbprofileimage = [(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:pin.image];
    //UIImageView *leftIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    //leftIconView = [view.leftCalloutAccessoryView [[UIImageView alloc]];
    //view.leftCalloutAccessoryView;

    // Keep a reference to the callout's image
    self.selectedCalloutImage = [(UIImageView *)view.leftCalloutAccessoryView image];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPlattegrondDetails" sender:self];
}
```

Then pass the image to the subsequent controller in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPlattegrondDetails"])
    {
        DetailViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.image = self.selectedCalloutImage;
    }
}
```

You can then display / use it however you like.